# How to configure dotnet core web app for different environments under IIS

Tags: .net-core, iis-6, production-environment

We have a `dotnet core 3.1` web app which we are trying to host under `IIS 6`. This all works fine on the hosted DEV environment, but when we move to the integration (or later) environment the application fails to start and does not get as far as logging anything to Insights.

The `.csproj` file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.7" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

On the development environment we have this `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_URLS" value="https://dev-apps.myapp.com/MyApp" />
          <environmentVariable name="LOCAL" value="false" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

This works perfectly. However, if we change the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value to `Integration` (as we would when deploying to the integ environment) the application fails with a 500 error.

I tried adding this line to the working `web.config`, but it appeared to have no effect (as mentioned in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0)):

```
<environmentVariable name="DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT" value="Integration" />
```

How can I tell the application that it is hosted in a non-dev environment and thus to use the appsettings.*.json for that environment?

Our settings files are these:

```
appsettings.json
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.Integration.json
appsettings.ProdSupport.json
appsettings.Production.json
```

We are not using `dotnet publish` but are simply building using:

```
dotnet build MyApp.csproj
```

Comment: Did you check the [supported platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#supported-platforms) list? Not sure, that you can run IIS 6 on Windows 7 or Server 2012

Comment: IIS 6 is definitely running successfully for us on Windows Server 2012 and in the DEV environment it is hosting this application without problems. It is only the later environments where it is causing a problem. As described, even in the DEV environment when we change the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value to anything but `Development` it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it turned out that we were using the [PersistKeysToFileSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-5.0#persistkeystofilesystem) method of persisting the data protection keys across multiple servers. This was failing because, in that environment, the one server did not have permission to write to the next in that location.